# Looking for some sort of wifi Amplifier

Tags: wifi

I have a 2-floor house, the router is located on the first floor.
On the second floor, the reception is a bad in some rooms and better in others.
I'm looking Amplifier/Router that can receive network cable and publish it as WIFI.
And in the same device, I'm looking for a way to receive wifi and publish it better.
I prefer Xiomi products.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many offerings that should suffice. I have a Netgear Wifi extender which has a Gigabit network port, which directly addressesyour question:

http://www.netgear.co.uk/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/EX6120.aspx

But you may also want to consider a Wifi Homeplug - Again, I also have a Netgear offering; you get a powerline adapter/homeplug at one end, and another plug that also has a built-in Wifi access point for the other end.

https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/powerline/XWNB5201.aspx

In this case, the Wifi is only N-standard rather than AC, but the benefit is that you don't need to run cable through the house.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for Wi-Fi repeaters or extenders. You don't need a network cable for this. Xiaomi has them but there are other companies too
[image: Xiami Wi-Fi Repeater]

Here's from another company (Netgear)
[image: Netgear Wi-Fi Repeater]

Comment: Thanks, But I want to have both of the options as written on the question. Cable and WIFI. Thanks